# react webpack less loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

Hi I run an old reactjs application with react 15.6. so I need webpack 4.

I need an less loader now I installed v 6.2 and added this in webpack:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
 },
```

But Now I got this error:

[image]

Whats wrong in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'less-loader'
            ]
        },
```